# How can I create a toggle like lightning checkbox toggle but using visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning

How can I create a toggle like the lightning checkbox toggle but using visualforce. I'm having a hard time to find this solution.

Comment: Hi Leonardo, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. When asking questions here, we expect some good faith effort to research or solve a problem before posting. Please also try to read tag descriptions and only select those which are actually relevant to your topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use [Checkbox Toggle](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox-toggle/) from  Lightning Design System.**
**Take in mind that you need to applyLightning Design System to VP as written here :   [Applying SLDS to Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_apply.htm)**

So it would look like this :

```
<apex:page controller="SalesUserProfileGraphicalAnalyticsCtr"  lightningStylesheets="true" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
  <apex:slds />
  <div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid">
      <span class="slds-form-element__label slds-m-bottom_none">Toggle Label</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-toggle-16" value="checkbox-toggle-16" aria-describedby="checkbox-toggle-16" />
      <span id="checkbox-toggle-16" class="slds-checkbox_faux_container" aria-live="assertive">
         <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
         <span class="slds-checkbox_on">Enabled</span>
         <span class="slds-checkbox_off">Disabled</span>
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
</apex:page>
```